# Results cache for Oracle 10g

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g

I've read that [Oracle 11g has a results cache feature](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=503) and I could really benefit from it. However, my client has Oracle 10g. Is there any sensible way to emulate it in a web application powered by PHP/5.2 that connects to a remote Oracle 10g server via ODBC (with Oracle's driver, not Microsoft's).

The idea is to cache complex queries on large tables that normally return small data sets and make sure that cached data gets discarded when the underlying tables changes (it doesn't need to be immediate, a one hour delay is acceptable).

I can install new software on the web server (not the Oracle server) and I could probably switch to OCI8 if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at materialized views in the database with [stale tolerated](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4541191739042).

Comment: I didn't know about that switch, I will definitively read about it. I've used materialized views in the past as a sort of cache for certain figures (e.g., total sales per store and month calculated from individual invocies) but, as global caching solution, it isn't as generic as I'd like. I have no way to know the exact queries beforehand because there're many filters involved.

Answer (score 1):

[memcached](http://memcached.org/) is an option.

But your client needs to upgrade to 11g since 10g support ends on 31-Jul-2011, they could purcase extended support until 31-Jul-2013. (this info could have changed)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a little further? I understand the storage features but, can memcache help to detect or keep track of obsolete data?

Comment: Not the same way that result cache does. In 11g there is also CQN so that you can update your cache http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use the In Memory Database Cache option of 11gR2. It also works for 10.2.0.4. This is a spin off from the TimesTen aquisition and you can use it to define a write through cache on your application servers. This allows for very fast returns. It scales wonderfully well, combine the app servers with the cache grid servers. In your case it could be fine to use mviews, if the data set to be scanned is large. If it is just complex, the cache will work fine, even for tables that are constantly modified.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? As expected, the `RESULT_CACHE` hint has no apparent effect on 10g :-?

Comment: the IMDB cache option allows you to cache tables closer to the application, making VERY fast data access possible.  The result cache does not work at all since it is 11g or higher, the IMDB cache can be used from 10.2.0.4 but works differently. (and is a separate licensed option)